# Dispose not working when used with Timer in Dart / Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

How can I get it to work?

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

And this is what I have:

```
class _ListCell extends State<ListCell> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => ListCell());
  }
```

Constantly getting the error:

```
 Error: The getter 'timer' isn't defined for the class '_ListCell'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the timer variable is defined out of the scope of the `dispose` method. This is because you defined the variable in the `initState` method.

**Solution:**

Move the definition of the `timer` variable outside the `initState` method like this:

```dart
class _ListCell extends State<ListCell> {
  Timer? timer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => ListCell());
  }
  
  ...
```

Since the `timer` variable is now nullable as it is of type `Timer?`, you need to use the null-check operator on it in the dispose method.

```dart
 @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Checkout Dart's [Lexical Scope](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lexical-scope)

Comment: If I do that, I get this:  Error: Field 'timer' should be initialized because its type 'Timer' doesn't allow null.

Comment: Use `Timer? timer;`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Perfecto, thank you so much!

Comment: PS: what would be the difference between timer?.cancel and timer!.cancel?

Comment: Oh. I meant to write `timer?.cancel`. The difference is that `timer?.cancel()` means that the `cancel()` method will only run if `timer` is not null while `timer!.cancel()` means the `cancel()` method will run regardless so this is to be used when you're absolutely sure the variable is not null.